# javascript function display in body

Tags: javascript

I've got this location script:

```
<html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>

<body>
 <p id="demo">&nbsp;</p>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
   x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;    
  }

window.onload = getLocation();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and it works perfect but what I want to do is to display the coordinaes in my body one more time without copy the same script. I just want something like php code echo $coords for example?

Comment: Save your javascript code as a function that takes one argument which is the "<p>" tag where you want to display results and whenever you want to display coordinates call this function.

Comment: cant you show me how? I have no idea

Comment: look at the answer of @Gurpreet Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop using `x` as a global. Make it an argument of getLocation() (and give it a more intention revealing name).

`showPosition` only gets called from `getLocation`, define it inside `getLocation`, then it can use the same variable.

```
function getLocation(target_element) {

    function showPosition(position) {
        target_element.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
            "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    }

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        target_element.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

getLocation(document.getElementById("demo"));
getLocation(document.getElementById("some_other_element"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call getLocation and pass the element id where you want coordinates.

```
  function getLocation(elem) {
        var x = document.getElementById(elem);

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
        else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }

        function showPosition(position) {
            x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>Longitude:  " + position.coords.longitude;
        }

    }

    getLocation('demo');
    getLocation('demo1');
```

HTML:

```
<p id="demo">&nbsp;</p>
<p id="demo1">&nbsp;</p>
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FeaZJ/)

Answer (score -1):

```
<body>
<p id="demo">&nbsp;</p>
<script>
window.onload = getLocation();

var x=document.getElementById("demo");
var locationString="";

function getLocation(){ /*the rest of your code */ }
function showPosition(position)
{
  locationString = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

  x.innerHTML=locationString;
}

</script>
<!-- the rest of HTML here -->
<p><script>document.write(locationString);</script></p>
</body>
</html>
```